# Polymerjs object bracket notation and data binding

Tags: polymer-1.0

When I am trying to bind data to an object property with bracket notation, it does not work

```
    {{myObj[variable]}}
```

So I created a function

```
    _convertObj(variable){
          return this.myObj[variable];
    }
```

then displaying the data works with below code

```
{{_convertObj(variable)}}
```

but for two way data binding to work if I use the below code it doesn't work

```
<input type="text" value="{{_convertObj(variable)::input}}" />
```

Is there a standard way of doing this which I am unable locate in documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved it myself by using computed binding

```
<input type="text" name="{{variable}}" value="{{_computeObjData(formData.*,variable)}}" on-input="_changeData" />

_computeFormData: function(formDataChange, name) {
    return formDataChange.base[name];
},
_changeData: function(e){
    this.set('formData.'+[e.target.name], e.target.value);
}
```